# .RECIPEPREFIX confuses autocompletion for Makefille targets

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, bash-completion

### without `.RECIPEPREFIX`:

the `Makefile`:

```
t1:
    ls

t2:
    ls
```

`gmake` completion works well:

```
gmake [tab][tab]
Makefile  t1        t2
```

### with `.RECIPEPREFIX`

the  `Makefile`:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX = >

t1:
> ls

t2:
> ls
```

it doesn't seem to work any, the second target `t2` doesn't show up:

```
gmake [tab][tab]
Makefile  t1
```

### Question

I wonder if it's due to my setup or [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), or Make

My bash-completion version:

`bash-completion: stable 1.3 (bottled)`

My make version:

```
gmake --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
```

Comment: GNU make doesn't provide any completion facilities, for bash or anything else.  You'll have to ask the folks who created bash-completion I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help from [scop](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/413#issuecomment-628406995), I updated to bash-completion@2

```
brew install bash-completion@2
```

and changed my login bash to 5 as [bash-completition@2 needs bash version to be ≥ 4](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/f0bf00a53677285600cdf8d82e754abb7f0e0644/bash_completion.sh.in#L6-L7) (following instruction on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196059/145789),

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash [username]
```

and it works now.